# ¿Cómo simular una aplicación de escritorio con Django y PyQt?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Estoy haciendo experimentos y me gustaría simular una aplicación de escritorio utilizando Django y PyQt, hasta el momento he logrado esto:

```
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl

HOST, PORT = '127.0.0.1', 8000

class HttpDaemon(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        self._server = HTTPServer((HOST, PORT), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
        self._server.serve_forever()

    def stop(self):
        self._server.shutdown()
        self._server.socket.close()
        self.wait()


class Window(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.httpd = HttpDaemon(self)
        self.httpd.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.httpd.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.load(QUrl("http://google.com"))
    # Como quiero que sea una aplicación local debería usar esto
    # window.load(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8000/"))
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Con este código se abre una ventana, como si fuera el navegador, y para este ejemplo abre google. Pero como quiero que sea una aplicación local en django supongo que debería usar algo como `window.load(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8000/"))`

¿Qué necesito agregar para que este experimento funcione con una aplicación de django localmente utilizando PyQt?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, ya te contestaron en Inglés, y no pude darle me gusta por que estoy betado, pero te la pongo acá:

"SimpleHTTPRequestHandler isn't set up to serve an application as complicated as Django. Django itself has a built in webserver for development purposes that you could use to start.

Django's manage.py provides access to a development server via the runserver command. But manage.py is just another Python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    print(sys.argv)
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Try integrating whatever is behind execute_from_command line into your application instead of SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.
"

Mas o menos lo que entiendo es que trates de ejecutar desde pyqt el servidor de django, puesto que el protocolo que tienen para manejar peticiones de tipo HTTP no puede servir Django.

Aconceja que ejecutes en su lugar el servidor de Django mismo para esta función.

Adicionalmente encontré este foro rebuscando en internet: [Django and PyQt](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/nTCZRzfyzlc)

Espero que sea útil.